# How to Test a Swift Script that's not in a Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, swift, testing

I started writing a basic swift script file and compiling it as:

`swiftc *.swift -o exporter`

Script doesn't do anything right now, but will have `export`, `import_files` etc. functions. I'm trying to find how I can test this basic script file?

Ideally, I'd have an exporter_test.swift file which I have all my unit tests.
Also, it's important to note that I'm fairly new to swift, so not sure if this is doable outside of Xcode.

`exporter.swift`

```
func export() -> {
    // will do exporting of data that's been imported in import_files
}

func import_files(files: [String]) -> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could execute it using the "swift" command line utility:

example:

Create a file (`test.swift`) with the following contents:

```
import Foundation
debugPrint("hello!")`
```

Then from the command prompt just run it with:

```
swift ./test.swift
```

and you should get:

```
13:24 $ swift ./test.swift 
"hello!"
```

Form within Xcode if you wanted it to execute via the build stages, then you'd have to add a "run script" stage.

1. In Xcode, click on the project in the `Project Navigator` (on the left)

[image]

2. On the right (main pane) select the target that needs to have the script run on

[image]

3. Click on the `Build Phases` tab

[image]

4. Click the `+` to add a new phase and choose `New Run Script Phase

[image]`

5. Edit the script as required... e.g.

[image]

Just note that in `5.` above, you'll probably have to rely on the build-time environment variables to reference files. Directly referencing a file i.e. as I did in my example will probably be caught up in a sort of "chroot" where `/` isn't actually `/` but rather a folder relating to the build directories.